# Excel: dynamic array formula

Tags: arrays, excel

[image]

I have an Excel sheet as in the picture. I want to make a variable array formula that uses the value in cell E1.

Cell D4 has the following formula, which works fine:

```
{=SUM(A3:A5*B3:B5)}
```

But, cell D5, where I try to use E5 together with OFFSET does not work:

{=SUM(A3:OFFSET(A3,E1,0)*B3:B5)}

Could anybody explain how to make this "dynamic" array formula work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the portion

`A3:OFFSET(A3,E1,0)`

would resolve to the range

`A3:A6`

i.e. a range comprising **4** rows. Evidently multiplying this range with one comprising just **3** rows (`B3:B5`) will error.

In any case, it's preferable to avoid the volatile `OFFSET`.

Try:

`=SUM(A3:INDEX(A3:A5,E1)*B3:B5)`

with `CSE` (although I have to confess that I'm not quite sure why you aren't using `SUMPRODUCT` without `CSE`).

I'm also not sure I understand the extent to which this set-up is 'dynamic', since the value in `E1` must be consistent with the number of rows hard-coded within the other range in the formula (`B3:B5` here). As such, in reality you only have one choice for the value in `E1`; all others will produce an error. Unless you intend to incorporate that value within the second range also? For example:

`=SUM(A3:INDEX(A3:A5,E1)*B3:INDEX(B3:B5,E1))`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try to reshape the range with OFFSET rather than changing the starting position.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A3, 0, 0, E1, 1)*OFFSET(b3, 0, 0, E1, 1))
```

This is the equivalent of,

```
=sum(A3:A5*B3:B5)
```